# linux - how to download .mp3 files whole site?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wget, httrack

I want to download all mp3 files in the website (even in root folder and sublinks).

For example i want to download all .mp3 links from the "http://example.org/musics/" and all sub-links.

How i cand do this?

thank you

Comment: Writing code would be a good start. We're not here to teach you how to do it. Or show you how to essentially rape a site. Do you have permission to steal all of the site's content? I'm guessing not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be using wget.

```
wget -r -A "*.mp3" http://example.org/musics/
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use wget:

```
wget -r --no-parent http://example.com/musics/
```

Assuming that the files are available for public download.
Just read the [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).

**Update:**

Reading through the man page, you will see this section:
http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files

It explains how to limit the files that it accepts when downloading. So you could add an accept option:

```
wget -r --no-parent --accept mp3,MP3 http://example.com/musics/
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `wget` command:

```
wget -o /home/music http://example.org/musics/music.mp3
```

Now, If you want to download all the “mp3” files from a website, you need to do some thing like this as following:

```
wget -r -l1 –no-parent -A.mp3 http://example.org/musics/
```